# Is there anything I can do to stop the slight page lag caused by this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, loops, optimization

I have this code cycling through my page, and it causes a slight page lag when a select box is checked. Is there any way to optimize the code? I am still very new to javascript so its possible that I mixed a few things up.

```
var OpeningEmployees = document.getElementById('opener');
var QuantityDDOptions = jQuery('#opener option').length;

var DropDownNames = new Array();
DropDownNames[0] = "opener";
DropDownNames[1] = "mid";
DropDownNames[2] = "closer";
DropDownNames[3] = "SRTW";
DropDownNames[4] = "CR";
DropDownNames[5] = "Aisles";
DropDownNames[6] = "BD";
DropDownNames[7] = "Fridge";
DropDownNames[8] = "AP";
DropDownNames[9] = "EPV";



OpeningEmployees.onchange = function () {
    var openerVals = $("#opener").val();
    for (var j = 1; j < DropDownNames.length; j++){
        for (var x = 0; x < QuantityDDOptions; x++) {
            var EmployeelNumLine = document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]).options[x].value;
            if (openerVals == null){
                jQuery("select#"+DropDownNames[j]+" option")[x].removeAttribute("disabled");
                $("#"+DropDownNames[j]).multiselect("refresh");
            } else if(openerVals.indexOf(EmployeelNumLine) > -1) {
                jQuery("select#"+DropDownNames[j]+" option")[x]['disabled'] = "true";
                $("#"+DropDownNames[j]).multiselect("refresh");
            } else if(!openerVals.indexOf(EmployeelNumLine) > -1){
                jQuery("select#"+DropDownNames[j]+" option")[x].removeAttribute("disabled");
                $("#"+DropDownNames[j]).multiselect("refresh");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some code missing. You need to explain what you are trying to do and what the code actually does.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if your loop is locking up the thread, you can refactor it as a recursive loop that is invoked using timeouts. That prevents the UI from freezing up.

For large values of `n`, this will freeze your browser:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    //dosomething();
}
```

This on the other hand, slows you down, but doesn't lock up the browser:

```
(function iterate(i) {
    if (i < n) {
        //dosomething();

        setTimeout(function () {
            iterate(++i);
        }, 0);
    }
})(0)
```